# Laravel - override connection but model still returns data from previous connection

Tags: php, laravel

So this is my process. I run a command and it creates a new connection. It then sets that connection as default. THIS works perfectly.

It also overrides another connection. However, since we can only have one default instead of creating a new connection and setting it to default it simply copies the old connection / replaces the database info and then overrides that connection.

I then immediately create a model that uses this connection. I even go into it and dump out `$this->getConnection()` and see that its pulled in my new settings and configs. My issue is that when I do a ->all() I am getting info from the PREVIOUS overridden connection. I have no clue why.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->env = $this->option('env'))) {
            (new Dotenv(base_path(), ".env.{$this->env}"))->overload();
        }

        $this->setClientConnection();
        dd(\Override::getModel('User')->changeConnection('webApp')->get()->pluck('login_name', 'users_id'));
    }

    /**
     * Create the database and a temporary connection
     *
     * @return null
     */
    protected function setClientConnection()
    {
        $clientDb = env('DB_DATABASE');
        $userDb   = env('DB_APP_DATABASE');
        // Create temporary connection
        $newConnection             = config('database.connections.data');
        $newConnection['database'] = $clientDb;
        config(['database.connections.' . $clientDb => $newConnection]);

        // Set new connection as default
        config(['database.default' => $clientDb]);

        // Override Webapp database
        $newUserConnection             = config('database.connections.webApp');
        $newUserConnection['database'] = $userDb;
        config(['database.connections.webApp' => $newUserConnection]);
    }
```

Just to reiterate, creating a new connection and setting it to default works perfectly. Creating a new connection and using it to override an existing connection SEEMS to work. `config('database.connections.webApp')` gives the new connection info. `(new App\User)->getConnection()` returns the proper config and database is set to the new database. looking at the model object, all appears right. Then I go to make a `->all()` call and it pulls in the overridden connection and pulls from the old database.

P.S. the changeConnection method i added to test out some things and to look at different protected attributes. Most of my dumping i did from there and it LOOKS like it should be using the new connection...till it actually makes the call...then no go.

Comment: What is Override? Is that a custom class?

Comment: Yeah it is our way of getting a model class and checking their are Any client specific overrides

Comment: I think you'll need to post the code of the Override class

Comment: That override method is simply a wrapper that either A) instantiates the model or B) instantiates the overriden model for that client if it exists and returns it. In this case, none of the clients have a User model override and therefore its just returning the basic User model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run get() on an Eloquent Model it runs the query on the `Illuminate\Query\Builder` object (after going through the Illuminate\Eloquent\Query\Builder wrapper function).

The`Illuminate\Query\Builder` object stores a reference of the connection object used for the query.

> Since your model is created first and then the connection is changed, the Query Builder object still uses the old connection

To solve this issue you need to create a fresh instance of the model query builder with the new connection

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. **Use the static function `on`** like so: `User::on('connection_name')->find($userId)`
2. **Use the `newFromBuilder` method** like so: `$model->newFromBuilder($model->getAttributes, 'connection_name')`
3. **Use the `newQuery` method** to get a fresh Eloquent builder like so: `$model->setConnection('connection_name')->newQuery()->find($userId)`
4. **Use the `fresh` method** like so: `$model->setConnection('connection_name')->fresh()`.

Do note however that the fresh method fires a new query whereas the other options set the connection without firing a new query.

Your choice of function would be based on

1. Whether you already have a model instance or whether you want to use static methods and
2. Whether you only need the builder object (like #3) or you actually need the model instance